# Hybrid Angular 1.x + Angular 6 App with both vanilla JS and TS files in Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-hybrid

I'm trying to build a hybrid app when the AngularJS files are both JS and TS.
I can't seem to add a route to a JS controller.

I'm relying on the following [example](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular-hybrid) and doing the following:

```
const statesConfigBlock = ['$stateProvider', $stateProvider => {
  $stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/layout/mainView.html',
    controller: 'mainController as main'
  })
}];
appModuleAngularJS.config(statesConfigBlock);
```

while I have a `mainCtrl.js` file that's defined as:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

(function(app) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('mainController', [
      function () {
        console.log("blah");

      }]);
})(app);
```

when I run the app I get:

> The controller with the name 'mainController' is not registered

but I do see it when I run in console:

```
angular.module('myApp')._invokeQueue.filter(function(el){
  return el[0] === "$controllerProvider";
}).map(function(el){
  return el[2]["0"];
});
```

Comment: Can you show where `appModuleAngularJS` is defined?

Comment: @yadejo same as `sampleAppModuleAngularJS` [here](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular-hybrid/blob/master/app/angularJSModule.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I managed to make it work. It might not be the best solution but here goes.

First, I created a js file that holds the declaration of the module:

```
appDependencies = [];
app = angular.module('myApp', appDependencies);
```

All the Angular 1.x controllers and services use the global variable `app` like so:

```
(function(app) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('mainController', [
      function () {
        console.log("blah");

      }]);
})(app);
```

Finally, the Angular 1.x module ts file uses the global `app` and adds dependencies to it:

```
...

declare const app: any;
declare var appDependencies: any;

export const appModuleAngularJS = app;

angular.forEach([
  uiRouter, upgradeModule.name
], module => {
  appDependencies.push(module);
});

...

const statesConfigBlock = ['$stateProvider', $stateProvider => {
  $stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/layout/mainView.html',
    controller: 'mainController as main'
  })
}];
appModuleAngularJS.config(statesConfigBlock);

...
```

Now, the order of the js imports in the `index.html` file is really important. The `app` deceleration file should come first, then all the Angular 1.x controllers and services and then the *.ts files that were transpiled to a js file.

This solution worked for me, but I'm more than happy to read a better one.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the response, ill take a look